# How to check if the css animation is done in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to detect if my css animation is ended in my app.

I have something like the following

```
  animation.prototype.nextStage = function(){
       this.ball.show().addClass('stage' + this.stage); //start the animation
       this.ball.on('animationend mozanimationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msanimationend',function(){
            //when animation is ended, do something for animation item itself….
        })
    }

   animation.prototype.isEnded = function(){
     // now sure how to check if the animation is ended outside of the animation obj.
    }


 function main(){
    this.ball = new animation ();
 }

main.prototype.checkAnimation = function(){
    this.ball.nextStage();
    if(this.ball.isEnded){
      //do stuff for something that is not part of animation items..
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to check if my ball animation is done in my main object. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried a promise or a callback?

Comment: execute `animation.prototype.isEnded` when the animation is complete. And possibly name it something that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

This way you add new event handler each time you call `nextStage`.

It'll be better to use something like:

```
function animation(ball, completeCallback) {
    var self = this;
    this.isEnded = false;
    this.ball = ball;
    this.ball.on('animationend mozanimationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msanimationend', function () {
        self.isEnded = true;
        if (typeof completeCallback === 'function') {
            completeCallback();
        } 
    });
}
animation.prototype.nextStage = function () {
    this.ball.show().addClass('stage' + this.stage); //start the animation
    this.isEnded = false;
}


function main() {
    this.ball = new animation(DOM_ELEMENT, this.completeCallback);
}

main.prototype.completeCallback = function () {
   alert('ANIMATION IS DONE');
};

main.prototype.checkAnimation = function () {
    if (this.ball.isEnded) {
        //do stuff for something that is not part of animation items..
    }
}
```

Call `this.ball.nextStage();` when you want to animate.

Comment: thanks for the tip, however, the animation needs time to play and this.ball.isEnded is always get false. to reach self.isEnded=true, I am not sure how to set it up. +1

Comment: You can add a callback. Check out the changes in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing something async, you could use a promise or a callback. Passing a callback like this may work for you:

```
animation.prototype.nextStage = function (callback) {
    this.ball.show().addClass('stage' + this.stage); //start the animation
    this.ball.on('animationend mozanimationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msanimationend', function () {
        if (callback) callback();
    })
}    

main.prototype.checkAnimation = function () {
    this.ball.nextStage(function () {
        //do stuff for something that is not part of animation items..
    });
}
```

And here's a possible promise implementation:

```
animation.prototype.nextStage = function () {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    this.ball.show().addClass('stage' + this.stage); //start the animation
    this.ball.on('animationend mozanimationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msanimationend', function () {
        def.resolve(true);
    });
    return def.promise();
}

main.prototype.checkAnimation = function () {
    var promise = this.ball.nextStage();

    promise.done(function () {
        //do stuff for something that is not part of animation items..
    });
}
```